# How to get the last URL link element using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

How do I get the last html link from a given page using BeautifulSoup? I am trying to get a link that contains lenta.ru in it. However, if a webpage contains more than one lenta.ru it prints every lenta.ru. However I would like to just get the last lenta.ru link which is the pointer link for the translation.

I am getting these results

```
http://lenta.ru/news/2012/09/03/ipsos/ https://uynaa.wordpress.com/2012/09/06/%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%b0%d1%80-%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%bd-%d0%b1%d1%8d%d0%bb%d1%8d%d0%b3/
http://lenta.ru/news/2012/09/04/endofobama/ https://uynaa.wordpress.com/2012/09/06/%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%b0%d1%80-%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%bd-%d0%b1%d1%8d%d0%bb%d1%8d%d0%b3/
http://lenta.ru/news/2012/09/04/response/ https://uynaa.wordpress.com/2012/09/06/%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%b0%d1%80-%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%bd-%d0%b1%d1%8d%d0%bb%d1%8d%d0%b3/
http://www.lenta.ru/articles/2012/09/05/threat/ https://uynaa.wordpress.com/2012/09/06/%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%b0%d1%80-%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%bd-%d0%b1%d1%8d%d0%bb%d1%8d%d0%b3/
http://lenta.ru/articles/2012/08/21/terranova/ https://uynaa.wordpress.com/2012/08/23/%d1%85%d2%af%d0%bd-%d0%b1%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d3%a9%d1%81/
```

expected output

```
http://www.lenta.ru/articles/2012/09/05/threat/ https://uynaa.wordpress.com/2012/09/06/%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%b0%d1%80-%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%bd-%d0%b1%d1%8d%d0%bb%d1%8d%d0%b3/
http://lenta.ru/articles/2012/08/21/terranova/ https://uynaa.wordpress.com/2012/08/23/%d1%85%d2%af%d0%bd-%d0%b1%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d3%a9%d1%81/
```

my code

```
import re
import requests
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

with open("./uynaa.txt") as inFile:
    uynaa_txt = inFile.readlines()

for tmp in uynaa_txt:

    html = urlopen(tmp).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

    for a in soup.select('div.entry a'):
        if "lenta.ru" in a.get('href', ''):
            print(a, tmp)
```

uynaa.txt

```
https://uynaa.wordpress.com/2012/09/06/%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%b0%d1%80-%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%bd-%d0%b1%d1%8d%d0%bb%d1%8d%d0%b3/
https://uynaa.wordpress.com/2012/08/23/%d1%85%d2%af%d0%bd-%d0%b1%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d3%a9%d1%81/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution

`soup.select('div.entry a')[-1]`

#### Explanation

`soup.select` returns a list. You can retrieve the last item in a list with `[-1].` If the page only has one link that matches, the last item will also the the first item, but this shouldn't cause you any issues.

```py
# full working code

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
example_page = """
<body>
<a href="http://lenta.ru/news/2012/09/03/ipsos/ https://uynaa.wordpress.com/2012/09/06/%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%b0%d1%80-%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%bd-%d0%b1%d1%8d%d0%bb%d1%8d%d0%b3/"></a>
<a href="http://lenta.ru/news/2012/09/04/endofobama/ https://uynaa.wordpress.com/2012/09/06/%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%b0%d1%80-%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%bd-%d0%b1%d1%8d%d0%bb%d1%8d%d0%b3/" ></a>
<a href="http://lenta.ru/news/2012/09/04/response/ https://uynaa.wordpress.com/2012/09/06/%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%b0%d1%80-%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%bd-%d0%b1%d1%8d%d0%bb%d1%8d%d0%b3/" ></a>
</body>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(example_page, "lxml")

print(soup.body.select("a")[-1])
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! However this code returns ```<a href="https://automattic.com/cookies">``` which is the last a tag. I am looking for the last a tag that is in the actual article. Which means it's the last p tag.

Comment: Did you read the response? You can very easily modify what I wrote to get the last of ANY tag type. You might have to do that a few times, but key idea is getting the last item from a list using [-1].